# How to order inside grouped elements by column?

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to order this:

```
|    id    |    title    |    created_at    |

 1                            12:00  
 2                            13:00
 1                            15:00
 2                            15:00
 1                            17:00
 3                            18:00
 1                            19:00
 3                            20:00
```

into this:

```
3    20:00
3    18:00
1    19:00
1    17:00
1    15:00
1    12:00
2    15:00
2    13:00
```

This peace of code does the job grouping id's:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select t.id, max(created_at) as maxca
      from table t
      group by t.id
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.id
order by tt.maxca desc, id;
```

The problem is that created_at appears in reverse order, like this:

```
3    18:00
3    20:00
1    12:00
1    15:00
1    18:00
1    19:00
2    13:00
2    15:00
```

How do I reverse created_at order inside each grouped id chunk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add another key to the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select t.id, max(created_at) as maxca
      from table t
      group by t.id
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.id
order by tt.maxca desc, id, created_at desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table order by id desc,created_at desc
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have to remove **tt.maxca** and add **created_at** in your grouping :

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select t.id, max(created_at) as maxca
      from table t
      group by t.id
     ) tt
     on t.id = tt.id
order by id desc, created_at desc;
```